Unable to evaluate statically - Angular Bootstrap with Environment Values
I have an Angular 14 App with a module like so:
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ useModuleA ? ModuleA : ModuleB ],
  providers:    [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ]
})
export class AppModule { }

The application build fails with a "Unable to evaluate this expression statically." error pointing directly at the useModuleA line. I understand this to be an issue with data not being available at compile vs runtime, however I don't understand how my usage of the useModuleA flag could lead to this. useModuleA is a boolean const set at the top of the app.module.ts file, and it is determined by reading a local hardcoded moduleUsage.json file like so:
import * as UseModuleData from "path/to/file.json";
const useModuleA = UseModuleData.useModuleA==="true";

I have tried various permutations of trying to load the json to set the module load behavior and haven't found anything that allows the build to succeed. Everything results in a similar static error. Is there some better way I am missing to allow a string in one file to set the behavior in this file?

I have a similar problem. Do you have a solution?
